# Convert Cypher query to a Gremlin query

Tags: graph, cypher, gremlin

I need to write a query like this Cypher one in Gremlin, and don't know how to do it. Please let me know how to do it

```
MATCH (a:grandfather) -- (b:father) -- (c:person) -- (d:son) -- (e:grandson) -- (f: greatgrandson ) -- (g:gggson)  
where tolower(c.DESCRIPTION) contains tolower("name") 
return a, b, c, d, e, f, g
```

Comment: Because of support for text predicates, on what Tinkerpop-compliant graph system do you want to use your query?

Comment: Adding to the comment by @HadoopMarc, Gremlin today does not have a built in `tolower` function. This is something we hope to add in the future. However, some implementations allow alternative ways to do this, so knowing which graph database you are using will help give you a better answer.